# Pandas drop duplicates based on 2 columns sometimes reversed

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks something like

```
    c1    c2    c3
1   A     B     x
2   A     C     y
3   B     A     x
4   B     D     z
5   A     B     y
```

As you can see, lines 1 and 3 are repeated if we disregard that `c1` and `c2` are different columns (or if they become reversed). However, line 5 is not. How can I drop rows based on columns `c1` and `c2`, regardless of where the repeated values are?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select columns by subset, sorting by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html),create new DataFrame from array and use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with filtering by inverse condition by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['c1','c2']], axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()]
print (df)
  c1 c2 c3
1  A  B  x
2  A  C  y
4  B  D  z
```

Or:

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['c1','c2']], axis=1)).duplicated().values]
```

Comment: I'm your biggest fan! Everytime I post a pandas question I honestly think you'll be one of the 1st to answer :) thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sosi - Hmmm, it depends, in SO is many really good pandas gurus :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok let us try something new frozenset, will order your column in to sorted `tuple` , then using the `duplicated`

```
df[~df[['c1','c2']].apply(frozenset,axis=1).duplicated()]
Out[666]: 
  c1 c2 c3
1  A  B  x
2  A  C  y
4  B  D  z
```

Comment: Love this one! Never saw frozenset before.

Comment: @Erfan just small trick , and compare with np.sort apply + frozenset is much slower

Answer (score 0):

Also it could be done by sorting the row values using sorted():

```
df[~df[['c1','c2']].apply(lambda row: sorted(row), axis = 1).duplicated()]
```